# X-editable - select2 not working after Chrome Update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with (x-editable),
https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html

Select2 (dropdown mode) not working :(

after update Google Chrome to version 73.0.3683.86 (before update all was good)

the field disappears when clicked. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem too and found a quick solution proposed from the X-editable developers on Github (https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/1124).

Go to the select2.js file and change the line with this function:

```
mask.show();
```

To:

```
setTimeout(function () { mask.show(); }, 500);
```

Hope it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

X-editable is no longer maintained.

My solution is using the demo as an example, once clicked on the link right click on the search box and it works like it used to.